# Create Kafka Connect Connector to Monitor AWS RDS MySQL Database in AWS MSK (Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka) Cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-rds, aws-msk

I have a use case where I have to capture data change in the AWS RDS MySQL database via Kafka connect and publish it on a Kafka topic. For Kafka, I'm using AWS Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK) service. I have created the topic. I'm just left with the connector part so that the consumers can see the messages/events while consuming a topic.

**My question is, how can I create a Kafka Connect connector to Monitor AWS RDS MySQL Database in AWS Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK) cluster?**

I was following [Tutorial for Debezium 0.9](https://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/) to achieve this using Docker containers for Kafka and AWS RDS instance. I want to achieve this using AWS Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK) instead of Docker containers. I just want to use Docker containers on the consumer side only.

**Is this even possible or do I have to go with either AWS ECS or AWS EKS?**

Comment: Why can't you just replace the Kafka container connection properties with MSK? You'll still need separate instances for Kafka Connect, as that's not part of MSK

Comment: In AWS FAQs, it says, it has Kafka connect but not sure where it has explained its usage.

Comment: The AWS MSK FAQ claims that it is compatible with Kafka Connect. However, MSK does not include any managed Kafka Connect offering, i.e., there are no ready-to-use connectors provided by AWS that you can set up for MSK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a Kafka Connect connector to monitor AWS RDS MySQL database by an AWS Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK) cluster by following the steps below:

- AWS MSK cluster and AWS RDS MySQL database should exist in the same AWS VPC.
- Security group for AWS MSK cluster should exist with inbound rule for AWS RDS MySQL database with the appropriate port.
- Binary logging should be enabled and `binlog_format` should be set to `ROW` on the AWS RDS MySQL database.
- User should be created in the AWS RDS MySQL database which will be used by the AWS MSK cluster to connect to the database with necessary privileges like `SELECT` and `REPLICATION CLIENT`.
- Kafka Connect AWS plugin should be installed to connect to AWS MSK cluster. Download it as `JAR` file from the Confluent Hub and then copy it under the `plugin.path` directory in the Kafka Connect installation.
- Kafka Connect connector configuration file should be created with the `.properties` extension with appropriate properties. A sample configuration file is below:

  ```
  name=<CONNECTOR_NAME>
  connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  database.hostname=<RDS_MYSQL_HOSTNAME>
  database.port=<RDS_MYSQL_PORT>
  database.user=<RDS_MYSQL_USERNAME>
  database.password=<RDS MySQL password>
  database.whitelist=<LIST_OF_DATABASES_TO_MONITOR>
  database.server.id=1
  database.server.name=<DB_SERVER_NAME>
  database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=<KAFKA_BROKER_ENDPOINTS>
  database.history.kafka.topic=<KAFA_TOPIC_NAME>
  ```
- Kafka Connect worker should be started using the following command: `bin/connect-distributed.sh config/<CONNECTOR_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME>.properties`
- After that, send the Kafka Connect connector configuration by running the following command: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @<CONNECTOR_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME>.properties http://localhost:8083/connectors`

*Note: This is a generic solution and you can change it according to your use case. Also, don't forget to replace the following placeholders: `<CONNECTOR_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME>`, `<CONNECTOR_NAME>`, `<RDS_MYSQL_HOSTNAME>`, `<RDS_MYSQL_PORT>`, `<RDS_MYSQL_USERNAME>`, `<RDS MySQL password>`, `<LIST_OF_DATABASES_TO_MONITOR>`, `<DB_SERVER_NAME>`, `<KAFKA_BROKER_ENDPOINTS>`, and `<KAFA_TOPIC_NAME>` before proceeding.*

References:

- [Debezium connector for MySQL](https://Debezium%20connector%20for%20MySQL)
- [Debezium connector for MySQL - MySQL connector configuration example](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.4/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration)
- [Debezium connector for MySQL - Creating a user](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.4/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-creating-user)
- [MySQL database log files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html)
- [Welcome to the Amazon MSK Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/what-is-msk.html)
- [How to Use Kafka Connect - Get Started](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/userguide.html#install-a-plugin)
- [Running Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running)